# Android(Table layout)

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am trying to display a table layout.In that i have the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.budget1/com.budget1.Report}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class Tablelayout
```

My xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tablelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Tablerow>
 <Textview android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Enter your name">
     </Textview>
    <Edittext android:layout_width="150px" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Edittext>
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    />
    </Tablerow>

 <Tablerow>
 <Textview android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Spanning Two columns" android:layout_span="2">
     </Textview>
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    />
 </Tablerow>

</Tablelayout>
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android layout xml files are case sensitive. Use TableLayout, TableRow, TextView, EditText, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify Ids for your layout components. Try adding a unique ID for each TableRow, TextView, ...etc using parameter `android:id="@+id/your_desired_id"`

Answer (score 0):

I Edited your xml file like this, its working fine,

```
   <TableLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter your name"
                />


        <EditText
                  android:layout_width="150px"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Submit"
                />
     </TableRow>

    <TableRow

        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Spanning Two columns"
                  android:layout_span="2" />

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"
                />
    </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks vishwa..for trying...i got the answer...I want to have space between each row in the table..How can do that.??

Comment: Hi, put  android:layout_marginTop="10px" in your second tablerow as a attribute

Comment: Thanks vishwa.Its working..One more vishwa(don't mistake me)..Is it possible to show separation between rows in table layout.

Comment: i didn't get you..what type of separation you want

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092116/how-can-i-add-separating-lines-between-my-tablerows-that-are-created-programmati