# Adding divider in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to set a divider for the table columns that are dynamically created. My xml for TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableEdit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/table_header_divider"/>
```

The part where I dynamically added the columns:

```
TableRow headerrow = new TableRow(this.getActivity());
addTableHeader("Type", 175, headerrow);
addTableHeader("Exp", 175, headerrow);
headerrow.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.getActivity(), R.drawable.selector_table_header));
headerrow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tableEdit.addView(headerrow);

private void addTableHeader(String title, int colWidth, TableRow headerrow) {
   TextView textview = new TextView(this.getActivity());
   textview.setText(title);
   textview.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(colWidth, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   headerrow.addView(textview);
}
```

However, the divider image is not showing at all. Any ideas? Or is there any way to set the divider programatically? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share screen shot how you want output?

Comment: Can you please check this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204184/how-to-set-the-divider-between-tabs-in-tablayout-of-design-support-library

Comment: @hyperfkcb https://stackoverflow.com/a/17411401/7666442

Comment: @FalduJaldeep wrong question link its for **`TableLayout`** not for **`TabLayout`**

Comment: @NileshRathod That means I need to create linear layout then wrap the text view together with image view? Is there any other alternative by not creating new linear layout?

Comment: @hyperfkcb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092116/how-can-i-add-separating-lines-between-my-tablerows-that-are-created-programmati

Comment: @NileshRathod The second link is for table rows. But mine is more of column :(

Comment: @hyperfkcb that link is for reference you need to use `view` for devider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void addTableHeader(String title, int colWidth, TableRow headerrow) {

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText(title);
    textview.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(colWidth, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    headerrow.addView(textview);

    View v = new View(this);
    v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(3, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    headerrow.addView(v);
}
```

**EDIT** you can add a boolean flag to check weather you need to add divider or not

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TableLayout tableEdit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        tableEdit = findViewById(R.id.tableEdit);

        TableRow headerrow = new TableRow(this);
        addTableHeader("Type", 175, headerrow, true);// send true if you want to add devider
        addTableHeader("Exp", 175, headerrow, false);// send false if you don't want to add devider
        headerrow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        tableEdit.addView(headerrow);


    }

    private void addTableHeader(String title, int colWidth, TableRow headerrow, boolean flag) {

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText(title);
        textview.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(colWidth, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        headerrow.addView(textview);

        if (flag) {
            View v = new View(this);
            v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(3, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

             ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = 100;
        params.rightMargin = 200;

        v.setLayoutParams(params);
            headerrow.addView(v);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool thanks so much! But the divider line is too close to the next column as per the screenshot in the question. I tried to add paddingRight but it does not shift at all. Any ideas?

Comment: @hyperfkcb sorry i didn't understand, if you a new query please post n new question with more detail so other user can try to help you my friend